# Bootstrap navigation not going up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My mobile view navigation when clicked goes down but won't go up when clicked again.
Here's the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}kb/img/kenya-buzz-logo.gif"></a>

        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                {% recursetree top_menu %}
                  <li class="stackAuto">
                    <a href="{% if node.url_override %}{{ node.url_override }}{% else %}{{ node.get_absolute_url }}{% endif %}" title="{{ node.title }}" class="stackContent{% if node.id == page.id or node.id == page.parent.id %} current{% endif %}">
                      {{ node.name }}
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  {% endrecursetree %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

It's hosted on http://www.kenyabuzz.com/mobile

Comment: Your code isolated works. (http://www.bootply.com/C5KbFzAMNE) But you habe a lot of html validation errors. My guess is that they are causing the problem. Get rid of these errors and try again.

Comment: thanks i tried looking at the error on my page 'www.kenyabuzz.com/mobile' with firebug I didn't get one, how did you view yours?

Comment: include bootstrap js and jquery link

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I've included bootstrap js and jquery in the body not the head could it be causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code in itself works fine.. the Proof is your [Bootply link right here](http://www.bootply.com/C5KbFzAMNE#)
 
I checked your code and you are running local versions of Jquery and bootstrap.

- Check what version of bootstrap you downloaded. Maybe you downloaded version 2 but you are using version 3 to write your code. [Find the difference between Bootstrap 2 and 3 here](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/) and maybe Jquery too

but then running your page through the [Html Validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kenyabuzz.com%2Fmobile&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), it says you have a lot of stray end div and a lot of duplicate IDs. This might not be the cause but fixing this little problems sometimes have proven to fix the big problems so my advise right now is:

- Make sure your IDs are unique, if you want to apply styles to many div, use classes
- Make sure all open divs are closed and that you don't have div lying around idle which is the case right now
- Make sure you don't have useless tags that do nothing or are not used by your javascript
- Make sure your other plugin or other `Css` classes do not cause conflict with Bootstrap `nav`, `navbar`, `collapse`, classes or at least you make sure you handle the conflicts well
- If you have another `dropdown` you want to make sure the `id` of the dropdown is different from this one, the data-target in the button for that one is also pointing to the right ids
- If you implement changes to your files and nothing seem to change, make sure you uploaded your files correctly via ftp, in the correct path and if it is still not working, you should try clearing your cache files

You mentioned that you included your `bootstrap` and `jQuery js` in the body and not in the head. That is totally fine.

Comment: I've changed to hosting online for bootstrap and jquery but it still won't work. I'm now trying to remove the errors. I did realise it works offline but not online not sure why.

Comment: it wasnt working at first and now it works for me on http://www.kenyabuzz.com/mobile right now. It didn't work yesterday but it does work today. Try clearing your cache: with this link for chrome: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183083?hl=en